# oAuth 2 implementation before moving google container

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running two restful apis, one with http and the other is with udp.
They are running on premise infrastructure and within next few release, we'd need run them as google container once we dockenize them 
Before we put the service up in cloud and all that, we need to implement oauth!

My question is that where to start and how we should approach implementing oauth 2 considering the road map I described?

Truly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on what you want to use OAuth2 for.

One option is toThere are OAuth2 implementations for most languages (e.g. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Index)

This allows you to keep your own login/password system.

If you'd rather delegate the auth and identity to a provider like Google, then you just need to implement the OAuth2 dance to get a user's identity from Google, see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect for more details.

(and when it comes time to use container engine, visit us on IRC #google-containers if you have questions about containers and Google!)

Comment: what if all i need is to authenticate the client with public/private key. Similar to google service account where you have clientid and p12 key file.